# POE daisychain design question

Tags: poe

I would like to design a slave device that can communicate with POE in a daisychain configuration. I am going to use dual RJ45 port but in terms of connection of the transformer circuitry, I have no idea. Could you help about the daisychain configuration? How can I make the dual port connections to the slave device? Is there a need for additional controller or a switch?

Best.

Comment: what device do you want to control/connect? do you want to experiment with using a MCU?

Comment: Yes there will be an MCU with 10/100 MAC

Comment: What is the protocol of communication? Daisychain? You should look up the MCUs that can use this protocol and use one of these mcus, start from there.

Comment: ethernet protocol

Comment: Daisychain, as in an integrated switch like KSZ8563 or KSZ8863? And I assume you want to chain the PoE power too? This could use some clarification.

Comment: I would like to use ethernet + power over rj45 cable for 5 slaves in series.Each slave has two rj45 ports in and out for the next device. The question is "Is it possible to do that?" if so How?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want PoE in and PoE out, i.e. act both as a PSE and a PD, also known as "passthrough PoE"? How long is the chain? How much power does each device need? What Ethernet speeds do you need? Are you connecting other devices than your own at either end? Are you looking for standard (802.3af/at/bt) active PoE, or non-standard passive PoE?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a direct answer, but If I were you, I would start by using a [Arduino Ethernet board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/11229)

[image: Arduino Ethernet w/o PoE]

(or a Arduino Ethernet shield)

This will help you jump-start using the ethernet protocol, and doing basic communication between your devices, using all the arduino's available libraries and the hundred of tutorials on the arduino along with its community.

Talking about daisychain configuration is a bit early, since your protocol you want to start using is Ethernet. First try to master this one, and then you can proceed to daisychain.

Regarding the hardware, if you do not want to use the Arduino board:

After you have managed to do some basic communication using the shield/arduino with ethernet, you can start building your own pcb/board and get rid of the arduino board.

Regarding the software/firmware, if you want to get rid of arduino IDE:

Also, going a step further, you can start digging in the libraries of arduino IDE that you used, see how everything works via datasheets and get rid of the arduino IDE as well, and make your own libraries and compile using ARC-C (microchip studio).

Comment: This is not an answer to my question

Comment: You needed help on the connections/schematics? When I read "Could you help about the daisychain configuration?" I thought of software-based help

Comment: yes The question is I have one slave unit with communicates with poe and I would like to place two rj 45 ports to connect multiple slaves in a daisy chain configuration. How can I do that on the schematics? any IC solutions? etc.

Comment: @oggy you likely want to search for "passive hub ethernet wiring", which will cover your data daisy chaining problem. No idea about power